# How to update a preference summary in android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-settings

In settings page of my app there are two `EditTextPreference` (s) When I change the value, the summary has to be updated. Right now it updates the summary as soon as I enter the values in the `EditTextPreference` (s) and hit OK. But when I restart the application the summary changes back to the default value. But the new value stays in the `EditTextPreference` (I can see when I open it). The summary gets updated again when I enter a new value in the `EditTextPreference`.
How to make the summary updated from the user input every time ?

Here is my code :

**SettingActivity.java**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();

    setTitle("Settings");
    ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}



public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_layout);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        Preference pref = findPreference(key);
        if (pref instanceof EditTextPreference) {
            EditTextPreference listPref = (EditTextPreference) pref;
            pref.setSummary(listPref.getText());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

**settings_layout.xml**

```
 <EditTextPreference
        android:capitalize="words"
        android:dependency="email_switch"
        android:defaultValue="@string/default_email_address"
        android:key="example_text"
        android:summary="@string/pref_description_email"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="@string/pref_email_address_text_title"
        android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress" />
 <EditTextPreference
        android:capitalize="words"
        android:dependency="sms_switch"
        android:defaultValue="@string/default_mobile_number"
        android:key="example_text1"
        android:summary="@string/pref_description_sms"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="@string/pref_mobile_number_text_title"
        android:inputType="phone"/>
```

P.S. I call this in my MAIN Activity

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings_layout, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onCreate()` method of the `SettingsFragment` class, you need to get a reference to your `SharedPreferences` and then run the `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` method.  Your `onCreate()` should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_layout);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    //if you are using default SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

    onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPrefs, getString(R.string.key1));
    onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPrefs, getString(R.string.key2));

}
```

Where `key1` and `key2` are your preference keys (`example_text` and `example_text1` in your case) saved into your `strings` file.  I had an issue when doing this myself without string references, which is why I recommend to extract them.

Comment: Sweet!  Also if you ever end up adding more preferences, you need to just add another one of those methods for each one with the key string.

Comment: Sure I'll do that :)